# Can't get Vue 3 child component to properly recognize prop data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs3, vue-props

I have a parent and child component in Vue 3. I'm using the options (old) API. I am passing data, an object with a bunch of different properties and values, as a prop like this:

```
/* Parent component */
<template>
  ...
  <child-component :itemData="itemInfo"></child-component>
  ...
</template>
```

- 

```
/* Child Component */
<template>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="itemInfo.isCustomizable">
</template>

<script>
  props: {
    itemData: Object
  }
  data() {
    return {
      itemInfo: this.itemData,
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I do this, I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties undefined (reading 'isCustomizable')`. Seems like maybe Vue is trying to read `itemInfo.isCustomizable` before the prop is fully rendered/loaded in the child component and then assigned to `itemInfo`. I'm not using the prop in the checkbox directly because I will need to take the checkbox data and save it in a database, and I know that mutating prop data doesn't fly.

In the past, I've remedied this by creating an empty object in my child component data and put the prop data in a watcher to replace my empty object. Something like:

```
data() {
  return {
    itemInfo: {
      isCustomizable: 0
    }
  }
}
...
watch: {
  itemData(oldVal, newVal) {
    this.itemInfo = newVal;
  }
}
```

But that does not seem to be working anymore, as well as just assigning the `itemInfo` data to be the `itemData` prop object.

I've run into this issue periodically since I've been using Vue, and although the above approach worked for me, there might be a better way that I don't know about. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Are you sure this line is valid code? '<child-component :itemData = itemInfo></child-component>' 

Should it not be: '  <child-component :itemData="itemInfo"></child-component>
'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The most clean solution for your `TypeError: Cannot read properties undefined (reading ...)`  problem that I know is to use "v-if" on the child component in the template of the parent component. In this way the child gets first rendered after the prop is actually available and its properties can be accessed.

```js
/* Parent component */
<template>
  ...
  <child-component v-if="itemInfo" :itemData="itemInfo"></child-component>
  ...
</template>
```

**2.** An alternative would be to initialize all the data that you need in the parent component.

```js
/* Parent component */
<script>
  ...
  data: {
     itemInfo: {
        isCustomizable: ''
     }
  }
  ...
</script>
```